# Beginner Python Help - Main Function

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I'm having some trouble working with this code:

```
def sumList(nums):
    sum = 0
    for num in nums:
        sum = sum + num
    return sum
print(sumList([5, 2, 4, 7])

    def numDict():
    num = dict()
    num = 5
    num = 2
    num = 4
    num = 7

print(sumList([5, 2, 4, 7]))

def main():
    nums = sumList()
    print(num[5])
    print(num[2])
    print(num[4])
    print(num[7])

main()
```

What I'm trying to do is test the sumList several times with the main function. Above, the numbers add together to produce 18. I want to incorporate the main function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'm not 100% sure on what you're saying but if you're just saying like how do I test sumList with the main function then you can do something like the following:

```
testCases = [([1,2,3],6) , ([1,1,1],3), ([10,10,12], 32)]
def main():
    for testCase, answer in testCases:
        if sumList(testCase) != answer:
            print("False")
    print("Everything checks out")

# then to actually call your main function like something similar to cpp
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That convention the `if __name__ == '__main__':` is commonly how you can access your main call in python.

If you're curious about the point of the **main** function, there's a really good Stack link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do). Stack to the rescue once again. Use it heavily!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
def sumList(nums):
    sum = 0
    for num in nums:
        sum = sum + num
    return sum

def main():
    print("Test One:")
    print(sumList([5,2,4,7]))
    print("Test Two:")
    print(sumList([1,2,3,4]))
    print("Test Three:")
    print(sumList([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]))
```

This should produce output like this

```
Test One:
18
Test Two:
10
Test Three:
2.0
```